# Clone form input value as text immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Is it possible to clone the value from

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

and

```
<input id="name" type="input" />
```

as pure text into a div or paragraph tag immediately?

Example: if **"123"** is typed in it will clone **"123"** into the div with no delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the keydown event and a short 10 ms delay (or possibly less, anything less than 30 is not noticeable by the user).

```
$("#text").on("keydown",function(){
    setTimeout(
        // proxy callback to `this` rather than `window`
        $.proxy(function(){ 
            $("#target").text(this.value);
        },this)
    ,10);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Qrug/

Edit: If you don't like or understand `$.proxy`, it could also be written as:

```
$("#text").on("keydown",function(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#target").text(that.value);
    },10);
});
```

Comment: why `keydown`/`delay` instead of `keyup`?

Comment: Because keyup will only fire when the user releases the key, presumably not the expected behavior if the user holds the key pressed for more than a second.

Comment: @Mathletics for some users who just kept the keys pressed and not released

Comment: @KevinB I would use `keypress` instead.. updated my post too http://jsfiddle.net/7Qrug/2/

Answer (score 4):

You should use `keyup` event on `textarea/input` and inside the handler update the `div/p` tag with the value of `textarea/input`

**Example:**

```
$('#mytextarea').keyup(function () {
   $('#myDiv').text(this.value);
});
```

**Note:** See other answers for updating the div when key pressed and not released.

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyup` and `keypress` events for older browsers and `input` for modern ones.

```
jQuery('#text').on("keyup keypress", function() {
    jQuery("#div").text(this.value);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbu5b/) - keyup/keypress
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbu5b/1/) - input